# sending at commands with c++ on cubietruck

Tags: c++, at-command

I have cubieboard3 (cubietruck) and i'm trying to send AT commands from cb to my modem, but i'm stuck on reading the answer from the modem.
This is my C++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>

using namespace std;


int main(void)
{
  int fd; /* file descryptor for port */

  fd = open("/dev/ttyS1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)//if could not open the port
  {
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS1 - ");
  }
  else //if port opened
  {
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY);
      //sending data
    std::cout<<"Port opened!"<<endl;
    std::cout<<"Sending 'ATZ\r' "<<endl;
    int n = write(fd, "ATZ\r", 4);
    if (n < 0)
      fputs("write() of 4 bytes failed!\n", stderr);
    else std::cout<<"Data send!"<<endl;

    //reading data
    char buf [10];
    int f = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    if (f < 0) fputs("Reading failed!\n", stderr);
    else std::cout<<f<<endl;
  }
  return (fd);
}
```

and it returns me :

```
Port opened!
Sending ATZ
Data send!
Reading failed!
```

what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I changed 
fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, FNDELAY); to fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);
and it started to read correctly, but it started to sending some kind of a trash for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your code I do not see any strange things (other than returning fd, but that is not related to any of the modem behaviour). Testing the code on my machine it works fine, although I tested with `AT` instead of `ATZ`, and the read returned 0 because the program was too fast and tried to read before the modem had gotten around to providing a response. Commenting out the fcntl call makes the program read 6 bytes.

To debug further you might try running with `AT` instead of `ATZ` and see if that makes any difference since ATZ does some reset and clearing it is not unthinkable that there might be some side effects that causes your problem (although I do not think it is very likely. But it is simple to test for and should be eliminated as a possible cause).

However, not trying to rob you for the fun of writing a serial communication program, I will point out that I have written a program called [atinout](http://atinout.sourceforge.net/) which already does what you are trying to achieve with your program. Atinout is made for command line invocation like the following:

```
$ echo ATZ | atinout - /dev/ttyS1 -
ATZ
OK
$
```